# How to redirect in react if the user logged in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

Well before writing this question i have searched internet Basically it shows 3 solution i tried all they seems to be outdated

```
1. using history.push('/')
```

The problem i am facing with this method is that browser saying who the hell is push i dont know what she is to debug i try to console history i find it is undefined i have seen in the answer they

I am just copying their answers

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory()

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home")
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  )
}
```

but this does not work because useHistory import error it is outdated the other answers also is not usable like done with redirect again having import error

Please suggest me a good way to do this

Comment: what version of react-router are you having

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

history is depreciated since react-router version 6+, if you want to migrate then [follow](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) this link.

If you however freshly installed version 6+ then you can use **useNavigate**

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let navigate = useNavigate()

  function handleClick() {
     navigate("/home")
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  )
}
```

more on the topic [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#navigation)

Comment: This works tannks